# Rpi lockout keyboard for x seconds Python

Tags: python, keyboard

Ive made a python scrpit that detects keypress on numpad to run a function using getch (eliminates having script ontop all the time).

I did find 2 examples one uses *pyhooks* (win32) and other uses */sys/devices/platform/i8042/pserio%d/bind_mode* (not in any sys folders i could find)

```
import getch
import datetime
from time import sleep as sleep
import requests 
import re, sys 
d = datetime.datetime.now()
format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
now = d.strftime(format)

def sbuild1():
         with open ("build1.txt", a) as log:
          log.write("start at " + now + "\n")
          log.close()

def fbuild1():
         with open ("build1.txt", a) as log:
          log.write("finish at " + now + "\n")
          log.close()

def sbuild2():
         with open ("build2.txt", a) as log:
          log.write("start at " + now + "\n")
          log.close()

def fbuild2():
         with open ("build2.txt", a) as log:
          log.write("finish at " + now + "\n")
          log.close()

    # main
key=getch.getch()

if key == '1':
     sbuild1()
if key == '2':
     fbuild1()
    #and so forth
else:
     pass
```

The issue is if I tap twice by acident it runs job twice so im looking for a time out.

If I use *sleep* it still registers key press but waits till *sleep* is done then runs.

Im using a usb keyboard, rasperian & python 2.7

Comment: *"If I use sleep it still registers key press but waits till sleep is done then runs."* -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)#Program_state ...Ponder: "The output ... is completely determined by its current inputs **and its state.** [...] a computer program stores data in variables [...]  The contents of these [...] at any given point in the program's execution, is called **the program's state**"

Comment: Good to know (not a programmer by trade)..

Comment: I realise that may seem a bit a bit snarky but that's not the intent: If you know what the problem is and how it arises, then you should be able to predict and respond to it by tracking it in terms of *state*.  In this case you could use a variable to indicate when the job began, and if it is called again within a certain timeframe, discard that call.

Comment: So your saying do an *if pressed > 0 and < 30 pass else ...* ????

Comment: Basically.  I'm not a python user but there should be an easy way to get a time in milliseconds (or seconds) based on the system clock, which will increment regardless of what the program is doing.  Another way to do it is to set a boolean variable before and after the sleep -- but that won't work all by itself if all the keypresses from during the sleep get queued for handling afterwards.  In that case you need to decide on a short time period during which all the handling calls can be ignored.

Comment: You could also try turning off whatever mechanism it is that causes the events to get queued; it's not clear to me what that would be based on that code.